# Multiple Eclipse Instances With Oomph

Tags: eclipse

I know it was a bad idea even back then, but when I installed my Eclipse Neon, there was no zipped Eclipse, only the Oomph installer, and so now I have my Eclipse scattered over the entire hard drive.

The problem is we have dozens of application with hundreds of modules and thousands of Java projects, so of course, we have a lot of workspaces. Most of the time, more than one of these are open.

And here is where the problems begin, because just starting two Eclipse instances doesn't work (it was problematic before, now even the most fundamental features like auto completion won't work).

We found out via trial and error that you need to start Eclipse as an Administrator and with `-clean`, but that way Maven will stop working because of missing temporary files once you open another workspace. There might be other errors, but these are so unspecific and random I could only prove that the Maven one is due to the `-clean`.

It's only a guess that its Oomph's fault, but this module is the only one I know changed since the last installation (Mars). Since I'd rather not spend an entire day setting up another Eclipse without it I hope to find someone who can confirm (or deny) that this is indeed the source of the problem.

This is probably relevant: The only additional plug-ins I installed are Subclipse and some of the JBoss Tools.

How do I get Eclipse Neon to run multiple instances?

Comment: There are zip downloads without Oomph (they call them 'packages') - http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/

Comment: Did you file a bug? The maintainers should be able to confirm if this is an Oomph bug or not and maybe even fix the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "Eclipse scattered over the entire hard drive"? You should be able to perfectly control where you install Eclipse. The one thing with Oomph that may not be 100% transparent: it can use a "bundle pool" for storing plugins that are shared among several Eclipse installations - to drastically save on download time.

Comment: When you need to start Eclipse as an Administrator that smells like a bad way of installing. Did you install it as an Adminstrator (you shouldn't)? If not, can you figure out which files need admin rights?

Comment: FWIW, at work I typically have a handful of Eclipse instances running, sometimes Oomph-installed, sometimes from packages. Never observed a problem that resembles what you are reporting.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann We have given up on talking, submitting bugs or trying to contribute to Eclipse altogether. Judging from the reactions we got it's not something they want.

Comment: @StephanHerrmann Well, there is the workspace folder and at least _.swt_, _.p2_ and _.eclipse_ in the user folder and some of us had massive problems if they didn't delete all these before installing a new Eclipse. Also there's the Eclipse application's folder which did have some sort of configuration, but maybe not anymore. And you can't install without admin rights, there's some weird exception in the installer if you do (at least into the default _Program Files/_ folder of Win7 and Win10).

Comment: I strongly recommend, to install Eclipse into a location different from _"Program files/"_, that should solve the permission problem. Also having to delete any of `.swt`, `.p2` and `.eclipse` indicates an unusual situation. I can't remember ever doing so over the course of literally hundreds of Eclipse installs.

Comment: Regarding bug reports: can you please give one or more example reports that (you feel) weren't welcomed by the respective team? Maybe I can help there ... OTOH, note that Eclipse is a huge community and there are some "cultural" differences between individual projects ... Which project did you report to?

Comment: @StephanHerrmann With the seedy reputation I have on SO I'd probably do more harm than good to out my colleagues here. But there are a couple of bugs that remove existing E3 functionality, affect a lot of people are really old and where never fixed, like bug 411765.

Comment: Thanks for the bug reference, I pinged the Platform/UI team on the bug. I see, yes the transition to E4 caused some pain, and if you maintain your own plug-ins this may affect you even more than a regular user. However, since the initial release of E4 the community around Platform/UI has significantly grown, in size and diversity, so we can now see a constant stream of bug fixes coming in. A huge number has already been fixed over the years. Anybody waiting for a particular fix should not hesitate to (politely) ping on the bug at intervals, this _might_ catch the attention of a contributor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial answer: I used a Oomph-free package (like @greg-449 suggested) and deinstalled "Code Recommenders" and now it seems to work (even so the auto completion is still in the wrong order).