# Share Code Formatter Settings With Everybody

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

In Eclipse there are a couple of preferences for formatting code which are very important for sharing code with other people, like *Java -> Code Style -> Clean Up*, *Java -> Code Style -> Formatter* and *Java -> Editor -> Save Actions*.

Two of these have to be laboriously imported by hand for each and every workspace, and one has to be configured manually entirely. And if you forgot to you'll have a lot of problems even for small code changes and small teams.

So we want to do something to make it easier for our developers.

What are the options?

- configure everything manually - doesn't work because developers are lazy, forgetful and eager to start programming when opening a new workspace
- import entire preferences / copy the *.metadata*-folder - can be forgotten quite easily as well, and we break a lot of working preferences (like the JDK, which is different for each PC); also doesn't work once you've set everything up and started coding and realized that you forgot to copy the preferences
- add the profiles programmatically using a plug-in - I'd prefer that, but everything 
  related to the formatters is internal
- ...?

I thought it would be really easy to configure the relevant preferences, but for some reason it does not work. It seems it's not really intended to do this anyways:

```
        PreferencesAccess preferencesAccess = PreferencesAccess.getOriginalPreferences();
        ProfileVersioner profileVersioner = new ProfileVersioner();
        FormatterProfileStore profileStore = new FormatterProfileStore(new ProfileVersioner());
        IScopeContext context = preferencesAccess.getInstanceScope();

        List<Profile> profiles = profileStore.readProfiles(context);
        FormatterProfileManager manager = new FormatterProfileManager(profiles, context, preferencesAccess,
                profileVersioner);

        CustomProfile profile = new ProfileManager.CustomProfile("ACME", new HashMap<>(),
                profileVersioner.getCurrentVersion(), profileVersioner.getProfileKind());
        manager.addProfile(profile);
        manager.setSelected(profile);
        manager.commitChanges(context);
```

How do other companies configure preferences that should be used company wide? How to share them easily with everybody?

Comment: _Two of these have to be ... imported by hand ..._ which two are you referring to?

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann _Clean Up_ and _Formatter_ both have a import function, but for whatever reason it's only imported once per workspace.

Answer (score 0):

We use shared, project-specific settings wherever possible.

After importing all projects from the source code repository, there are only a few settings left that are specific to the local computer or unfortunately can't be stored alongside projects like the JRE, the maximum line width, and maybe a few more.

The downside of having project-specific settings, of course, is when changes become necessary. We usually have a 'master' project whose settings are changed and then copied to all other projects.

Maven archetypes can help to set up new projects with all the settings needed. For plug-in development, we usually have a plug-in project holding the production code and a fragment project for tests. here again, Maven achetypes may help creating both projects at once. See here for a very simple form: https://github.com/fappel/xiliary/tree/master/com.codeaffine.xiliary.archetype

If you rely on several workspace-wide settings that you like to share you may want to look into [Eclipse Oomph](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.oomph).

The project aims to solve most (all?) of what you might be looking for.

- workspace provisioning
- maintaining consistent project-specific settings
- installing an pre-configured IDE, tailored for working on a selection of projects

Comment: Committing IDE settings is a bit of a no-go, and for the hundreds of projects we have it's way to much work to copy the _.project_ files anyways. And Oomph is not working in a [professional environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39225379/multiple-eclipse-instances-with-oomph) yet.

Comment: Having a painless development environment setup doesn't come for free. Assuming that all projects (of the same kind) have the same settings, you could let a script do the copying. BTW, it is not the `.project` file that would need to be copied, it is the `.settings` folder.

Comment: And nothing about having the exact same file hundreds (if not thousands) of times  in your projects strikes you as inconvenient? It sure seems to be the Eclipse way, doesn't mean it works for a setup with multiple developers and workspaces and projects.

Comment: Eclipse does not have the concept of nested projects.
Hence you have two options to store your settings: workspace-wide or project-specific.

Despite the duplication and other drawbacks, I have found project-specific settings to be the best among the available choices for medium-sized projects (~ 40).

However, I'm just listing the options that I know of to address this problem. I'm sorry if that does not work for you for some reason.

Comment: @SteffiS. if you want to share a code formatter profile among all members of a team, it sounds like you'd have to agree on using Eclipse in the first place. After that, persisting `.settings` shouldn't pose any trouble. It's more like ideology that people preach against it. True, if IDE specific files are changed during each commit, this can become an annoyance, but files in `.settings` only change when you make relevant changes to your configuration, and then these need to be distributed to team members any way.

Comment: As of 2016, I can no longer think of a professional working environment _without_ Oomph, if you ask me :) - the biggest time saver in a long time.

Comment: @StephanHerrmann The thing is that we don't agree. Eclipse's quality is decreasing so fast that most people who had a choice switched to another IDE (which in turn makes it more important to get everybody the same formatting settings, because the defaults (might?) vary between IDEs dramatically).